# Plus 1 to variable with tkinter button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm very new in python, I'm trying give + 1 to "x" variable with tkinter button, can you help me figure out with it please

```
import tkinter as Tk

x = 0

root = Tk.Tk()

def add():

    x == (x + 1) # Here but seems wrong way 

Tk.Button(root, text='PLUS 1 to X', command=add,
        height=5, width=20,).pack(side=Tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing where the value of `x` is supposed to be displayed, and I'm not seeing how the successive values of `x` are supposed to be retained, in your code. Here's one simple way to do it:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> def add():
...     global x
...     x += 1
...     messagebox.showinfo(message=x)
... 
>>> from tkinter import messagebox
>>> x = 0
>>> adder = Button(root, text='ADD 1 TO X', command=add)
>>> adder.grid()
```

Setting `x` as a global variable allows you to change it within the function and keep the change after the function returns. As you probably know, `x += 1` means the same as `x = x+1`, i.e., the new value of `x` is 1 more than the old value.

Comment: you could also explain that [`==` is a comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comparison#value-comparisons) instead of assignment.

Comment: Oops, yes, you'll never get anywhere if you wait until `x == x+1`!

Answer (score 1):

You are using comparison operator (==) in place of assignment operator(=)

Corrected version

```
from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> def add():
...     global x
...     x += 1
...     messagebox.showinfo(message=x)
... 
>>> from tkinter import messagebox
>>> x = 0
>>> adder = Button(root, text='ADD 1 TO X', command=add)
>>> adder.grid()
```